# SQL instr equivalent in Django

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to check if given text contains in a sub string present in db,

> ex:- **string to search** - "my name is john"

> **string in db/column_name**- "john".

SQL query

```
select * from `demo` where instr('my name is john','column_name') > 0
```

What is the Django Equivalent of above query?

**NOTE** - The actual string is very large about 255 characters so I can't use regex to extract string as the input will be dynamic.

Comment: `string.find(str, [start], [end])`?

Comment: @Akina thanks, what will be the django equivalent query of this, as this find method is pure python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first use `annotate` to annotate your string to the query and then use the  [`contains` lookup [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains) on it to find if it contains the given column:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, F, Q, Value


queryset = TestModel.objects.annotate(
    search_text=Value('my name is john', output_field=CharField())
).filter(
    Q(search_text__contains=F('column_name')) & Q(search_text__contains=F('second_column_name'))
)
```

Comment: thank you so much man, this is big relief. Could please tell me how do I use AND in above query 
`.filter(  search_text__contains=F('column_name'),search_text__contains=F('second_column_name'))` 
I tried  this and I am getting **keyword argument repeated error**

Comment: @HarvindarSinghGarcha use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourModel(models):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

if you want to query for message substring try like this:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(message__contains='john')
```

in return you will get list of objects/db rows where the column (message) has a substirng of 'john'

Comment: The thing is I have a large text to be searched which is not static each time, I can't directly search 'john' as I will need to use regex and extract john from text to search in message. Any other way where I can use the string in db as sub string to check as the string in the given input string ?

Comment: Store your search_word in a variable and pass it in the place of 'john'.

Comment: I already tried that, in db we are storing name as 'john' and we are getting input as 'my name is john' so i want to check input against the db by using db_column value as sub string and input as string to be searched in.